# Center navigation bar (Bootstrap) items horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar with 2 icons evenly distributed.

[image: Navigation Bar Representation]

I am wanting to scale them horizontally so they are centered horizontally in relation to the navigation bar.

I think the viewbox of the svg's are cause it to not look visually centred.

I've tried playing with the size without much luck.

I did try justifying content which didn't work.
Then I tried adding padding to the icons to allow for them to move.

**Code:**

```css
.bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Style the navigation menu */
.navbar {
  width: 90%;
  background: #3CE18F;
  /* Forces the icons to not go outside the scrollbar. If we left it to invisble it would display 
  them outside. */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Curves the corners of the Nav Bar. */
  border-radius: 10px 10px 30px 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3%;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 48.6%; /* Four equal-width links. If you have two links, use 50%, and 33.33% for three links, etc.. */
  text-align: center; /* If you want the text to be centered */
}

/* Add a background color on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

/* Style the current/active link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.microphoneIcon {
/*  position: absolute;
    left: 65.36%;
    right: 26.29%;
    top: 54.22%;
    bottom: 0.46%;*/
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
  /* Similar syntax to box-shadow */
    /*background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
}

.cameraIcon {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#009578">
        <title>PWA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/navigationBar.css">
        <!-- Javascript Docs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/logo192.png">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Class for the Bottom Navigation Bar -->
        <div class="bar">
            <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light nav-fill">
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class='microphoneIcon' id='microphoneIcon' width="42" height="46" viewBox="0 0 42 46" stroke="grey">
                        <path d='M21 23.7571C25.0314 23.7571 28.2857 21.1043 28.2857 17.8179V5.93928C28.2857 2.65288 25.0314 0 21 0C16.9686 0 13.7143 2.65288 13.7143 5.93928V17.8179C13.7143 21.1043 16.9686 23.7571 21 23.7571ZM18.5714 5.93929C18.5714 4.85043 19.6643 3.95953 21 3.95953C22.3357 3.95953 23.4286 4.85043 23.4286 5.93929V17.8179C23.4286 18.9067 22.3357 19.7976 21 19.7976C19.6643 19.7976 18.5714 18.9067 18.5714 17.8179V5.93929ZM21 27.7167C27.7029 27.7167 33.1429 23.282 33.1429 17.8179H38C38 24.8064 31.6614 30.5477 23.4286 31.5178V37.6155H18.5714V31.5178C10.3386 30.5477 4 24.8064 4 17.8179H8.85714C8.85714 23.282 14.2971 27.7167 21 27.7167Z'/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class ='cameraIcon' id='cameraIcon' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="46" viewBox="0 0 50 46">
                      <path d="M 45 36 a 3 3 90 0 1 -3 3 H 6 a 3 3 90 0 1 -3 -3 V 18 a 3 3 90 0 1 3 -3 h 3.516 a 9 9 90 0 0 6.36 -2.637 l 2.49 -2.484 A 3 3 90 0 1 20.481 9 h 7.032 a 3 3 90 0 1 2.121 0.879 l 2.484 2.484 A 9 9 90 0 0 38.484 15 H 42 a 3 3 90 0 1 3 3 v 18 z M 6 12 a 6 6 90 0 0 -6 6 v 18 a 6 6 90 0 0 6 6 h 36 a 6 6 90 0 0 6 -6 V 18 a 6 6 90 0 0 -6 -6 h -3.516 a 6 6 90 0 1 -4.242 -1.758 l -2.484 -2.484 A 6 6 90 0 0 27.516 6 H 20.484 a 6 6 90 0 0 -4.242 1.758 l -2.484 2.484 A 6 6 90 0 1 9.516 12 H 6 z M 24 33 a 7.5 7.5 90 1 1 0 -15 a 7.5 7.5 90 0 1 0 15 z m 0 3 a 10.5 10.5 90 1 0 0 -21 a 10.5 10.5 90 0 0 0 21 z M 9 19.5 a 1.5 1.5 90 1 1 -3 0 a 1.5 1.5 90 0 1 3 0 z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to scale them horizontally. The display of the navbar must be inline-flex. I have added it.

As you have requested to scale them vertically. I have changed the CSS of a tag width.

Please take a look at the CSS. @Nitrogen

```css
.bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Style the navigation menu */
.navbar {
  width: 90%;
  background: #3CE18F;
  /* Forces the icons to not go outside the scrollbar. If we left it to invisble it would display 
  them outside. */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Curves the corners of the Nav Bar. */
  border-radius: 10px 10px 30px 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3%;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
}

/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  width: 100% !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 48.6%; /* Four equal-width links. If you have two links, use 50%, and 33.33% for three links, etc.. */
  text-align: center; /* If you want the text to be centered */
}

/* Add a background color on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

/* Style the current/active link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.microphoneIcon {
/*  position: absolute;
    left: 65.36%;
    right: 26.29%;
    top: 54.22%;
    bottom: 0.46%;*/
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
  /* Similar syntax to box-shadow */
    /*background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
}

.cameraIcon {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    filter: drop-shadow( 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#009578">
        <title>PWA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/navigationBar.css">
        <!-- Javascript Docs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/logo192.png">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Class for the Bottom Navigation Bar -->
        <div class="bar">
            <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light nav-fill">
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class='microphoneIcon' id='microphoneIcon' width="42" height="46" viewBox="0 0 42 46" stroke="grey">
                        <path d='M21 23.7571C25.0314 23.7571 28.2857 21.1043 28.2857 17.8179V5.93928C28.2857 2.65288 25.0314 0 21 0C16.9686 0 13.7143 2.65288 13.7143 5.93928V17.8179C13.7143 21.1043 16.9686 23.7571 21 23.7571ZM18.5714 5.93929C18.5714 4.85043 19.6643 3.95953 21 3.95953C22.3357 3.95953 23.4286 4.85043 23.4286 5.93929V17.8179C23.4286 18.9067 22.3357 19.7976 21 19.7976C19.6643 19.7976 18.5714 18.9067 18.5714 17.8179V5.93929ZM21 27.7167C27.7029 27.7167 33.1429 23.282 33.1429 17.8179H38C38 24.8064 31.6614 30.5477 23.4286 31.5178V37.6155H18.5714V31.5178C10.3386 30.5477 4 24.8064 4 17.8179H8.85714C8.85714 23.282 14.2971 27.7167 21 27.7167Z'/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class ='cameraIcon' id='cameraIcon' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="46" viewBox="0 0 50 46">
                      <path d="M 45 36 a 3 3 90 0 1 -3 3 H 6 a 3 3 90 0 1 -3 -3 V 18 a 3 3 90 0 1 3 -3 h 3.516 a 9 9 90 0 0 6.36 -2.637 l 2.49 -2.484 A 3 3 90 0 1 20.481 9 h 7.032 a 3 3 90 0 1 2.121 0.879 l 2.484 2.484 A 9 9 90 0 0 38.484 15 H 42 a 3 3 90 0 1 3 3 v 18 z M 6 12 a 6 6 90 0 0 -6 6 v 18 a 6 6 90 0 0 6 6 h 36 a 6 6 90 0 0 6 -6 V 18 a 6 6 90 0 0 -6 -6 h -3.516 a 6 6 90 0 1 -4.242 -1.758 l -2.484 -2.484 A 6 6 90 0 0 27.516 6 H 20.484 a 6 6 90 0 0 -4.242 1.758 l -2.484 2.484 A 6 6 90 0 1 9.516 12 H 6 z M 24 33 a 7.5 7.5 90 1 1 0 -15 a 7.5 7.5 90 0 1 0 15 z m 0 3 a 10.5 10.5 90 1 0 0 -21 a 10.5 10.5 90 0 0 0 21 z M 9 19.5 a 1.5 1.5 90 1 1 -3 0 a 1.5 1.5 90 0 1 3 0 z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work. No changes at all.

Comment: check out the snippet it works. do not forget to add an important for inline-flex.

Comment: I ran the snippet, the icons are not centered horizontally.

Comment: what do you mean by centered horizontal ? could you please explain me

Comment: @BathriNathan did you mean vertically? Because it's horizontally centered and not vertically centered.

Comment: I already had it vertically centered. I wanted to center them vertically in relation to the nav bar

Comment: @Nitrogen I have made them vertically centered as per my understanding. I hope this what you have asked. Please take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

put display:flex in to navbar div

```
.navbar {
  display:flex;
}
```

button in separate lines

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't work either. No effect at all.